# What is the key shortcut to close a project in Sublime Text 3?

Tags: sublimetext3

What is the key shortcut to close a project in Sublime Text 3? Do I have to create a new key bind, if so, what is it?

Thank you, I appreciate it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Ctrl + W` closes the tab you are working on. Currently there is no combination shortcut to close a project all together. You can create a new key bind, Instructions here : http://www.sublimetext.com/docs/key-bindings

Comment: That documentation is for Sublime Text ***1***, which is ancient. Try using the docs [here](http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/latest/customization/key_bindings.html) instead.

Answer (score 3):

You can define

```
{
"keys": ["ctrl+alt+w"], "command": "close_workspace" 
},
```

then you can close using **ctrl+alt+w**